# How to display 0:00 instead of NaN:NaN on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio

I have an audio player with a playlist but when I click on a new track it briefly displays NaN:NaN where I have the duration until I load the track. This is what I have but it's not working.

```
audioPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    var curmins = Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime / 60);
    var cursecs = Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime - curmins * 60);

    var durmins = Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration / 60);
    var dursecs = Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration - durmins * 60);
       if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; }
       if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs; }
     
      
      if (durmins !== 'NaN') {
        $('#duration').text(durmins+":"+dursecs);
        $('#current-time').text(curmins+":"+cursecs);
      }
 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isNaN`.

```
if (isNaN(durmins)) {
```

You can also use the property that `NaN` is the only object never equal to itself.

```
if(durmins !== durmins) {
```

Comment: @caseym No problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the entire calculation in an if-block and only if the property exists - perform the calculation - otherwise display "0:00" for both duration and current time

```
audioPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  if(audioPlayer.duration) {
    var curmins = Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime / 60);
    var cursecs = Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime - curmins * 60);

    var durmins = Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration / 60);
    var dursecs = Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration - durmins * 60);
       if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; }
       if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs; }
     
    $('#duration').text(durmins+":"+dursecs);
    $('#current-time').text(curmins+":"+cursecs);
  } else {
     $('#duration').text("0:00");
    $('#current-time').text("0:00");
  }
}
```

You coud also set duration and curentTime variables as "0:00" at the start and if the property exists update the variables. If tghe property doesn't exist - then the original value of the variables will be passed to the text elements.

```
audioPlayer.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  var duration = "0:00";
  var currentTime = "0:00";

  if(audioPlayer.duration) {
    var curmins = Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime / 60);
    var cursecs = Math.floor(audioPlayer.currentTime - curmins * 60);

    var durmins = Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration / 60);
    var dursecs = Math.floor(audioPlayer.duration - durmins * 60);
       if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; }
       if(dursecs < 10){ dursecs = "0"+dursecs; }
     
    duration = durmins + ":" + dursecs;
    currentTime = curmins + ":" + cursecs;
  }
  $('#duration').text(duration);
  $('#current-time').text(currentTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(durmins !== 'NaN')
```

condition checking did not work at all, here is the reason:

`number` type in JavaScript is actually the floating-point number following the IEEE754 spec. You will get `false` when running

```
NaN == NaN
```

or

```
NaN === NaN
```

since under the IEEE754 spec, NaN(Not a Number) is a special built-in value, any numbers (including NaN itself) comparing to NaN should get false.

The only way to check if a number is NaN or not is using function `isNaN(value)`

For more information about ieee754, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Answer (score 0):

Use   if (durmins) instead of   if (durmins !== 'NaN')

NaN means undefined variable. It is not a string. if (durmins) will check if the variable is defined and run the code if it is.